# Linux terminal and Python are mushed together

Tags: python, linux, terminal

When I run some commands, which work, for example neofetch, it gives me a Python error.

```
username@host:~$ as
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

It does that whenever I type an invalid command. This started happening after I installed Python 3.9. I am running Kubuntu with Python 3.10 installed by default.

Comment: I remeber getting same problem this command fixed it: sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken

Comment: Shells can use Python behind the scenes for some stuff. I wouldn't say that they're "mushed together". The shell is trying to defer work to Python, and that script it gave work to is crashing due to a missing library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Linux distributions tend to use **a lot** of python scripts for internal use; for this reason python gets installed with a plethora of libraries.

The error you are getting is because you replaced that fairly complete system python with a version of your own choosing without providing all the libraries the original came with.

The error you see is emitted by `/usr/lib/command-not-found`, a script using `python3` as found in the system path.

I strongly recommend that you re-install the original python packages and use e.g. `anaconda` for your specific python needs.

The main takeaway from this is:

**DON'T MESS WITH THE SYSTEM PYTHON**.

Answer (score -1):

try to find which python are you using using `which python` and uninstall the first python interpreter it finds.